# Process the CSV file with Pandas and compare the output of processed file with an existing file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to process a CSV file and extracting the hostnames and the saving the extraction into a file called `host_file1` and then comparing this file with already existing text file ie `host_file2`, So csv processing works fine.

Now, as i said i want to do some hostname comparison between two files, what i want is to match the hostname's in `host_file2` with `host_file1` , so if the hostname in `host_file2` but not in `host_file1` the print the hostname, don't print the hostname which are in both files.

I've tried something like below with set but it just give the difference not what i want.

```
#!/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
from __future__ import print_function
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
import pandas as pd
##### Python pandas, widen output display to see more columns. ####
pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
##################### END OF THE Display Settings ###################

df_csv = pd.read_csv(input("Please input the CSV File Name: "), usecols=['Platform ID', 'Target system address']).dropna()
hostData = df_csv[df_csv['Platform ID'].str.startswith("CDS-Unix")]['Target system address']
hostData.to_csv('host_file1', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')

with open('host_file1', 'r') as f:
    dataset1 = set(f)
with open('host_file2', 'r') as f:
    dataset2 = set(f)
for i, item in enumerate(sorted(dataset1 ^ dataset2)):
    print(str(item))
# shorter
"""
with open('host_file1') as f1, open('host_file2') as f2:
    dataset1 = set(f1)
    dataset2 = set(f2)
"""
```

**Two different hostname files:**

**host_file1**

```
vmhost01

vmhost02

vmhost03

vmhost04

vmhost05

vmhost06

vmhost07

vmhost08

vmhost09

vmhost10
```

**host_file2**

```
vmhost01

vmhost02

vmhost03

vmhost04

vmhost05

vmserver01

vmhost07

vmhost08

vmserver02

vmhost10
```

**Desired result:**

```
vmserver01
vmserver02
```

Comment: Thanks Guys for he heads up & different alternative suggestion altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need subtract sets:

```
for i, item in enumerate(sorted(dataset2 - dataset1)):
#alternative
#for i, item in enumerate(sorted(dataset2.difference(dataset1))):
    print(str(item))
    vmhost01
    vmhost02
    vmserver01
    vmserver02
```

And last solution with list comprehension:

```
s = set(dataset1)
out = [x for x in dataset2 if x not in s]
print (out)
['vmserver02', 'vmhost02', 'vmhost01', 'vmserver01']
```

Comment: Thnx jezrael,  this is correct one, i sould use the `-` operator rather using `^`  which is giving symmetric difference :)

Comment: jezrael, can i add the `host_file1`  as a  variable and compare with `host_file2` rather creating file on th disk?

Comment: @pygo - I think write to disk is not necessary, use `dataset1 = set(df_csv.loc[df_csv['Platform ID'].str.startswith("CDS-Unix"), 'Target system address'])` instead `with open('host_file1', 'r') as f:
    dataset1 = set(f)`

Comment: that seem more granular approach.

Comment: @pygo - ya, but it depends what need. If append to file and need compare with final big file I think is necessary `with open('host_file_file', 'r') as f:`

Comment: That's what i thought of because if file is big then  it can consume the memory and processing will be slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can do diff on the files to see the result

```
diff host_file1 host_file2
```

Above is a unix command. So, you need to use os or subprocess to run the command inside it.

if above are not files but dataframes then try below

```
diff = (host_file1 != host_file2).any(1)
print diff
```

One more solution.Here the column names of these two dataframes should ba same. If they are different then rename one of them to make it same as other.

```
import pandas as pd
host_file1 = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet_name = 2)
print host_file1
host_file2 = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet_name = 3)
print host_file2
pd.concat([host_file1,host_file2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Comment: i am not looking for subprocess unnecessarily as `set()` works for taking the differences   & symmetric differences, using subprocess & then using shell commnads here  will add no values indeed.

Comment: then you can go for second option for dataframes which I provided above.

Answer (score 1):

I think ur code is so complicated, how about code below:

```
import csv
with open("test.csv", "r") as t1:
    data1 = t1.read().split()
with open("test2.csv", "r") as t2:
    data2 = t2.read().split()
//u can exchange data2 and data1 to get what in data1 and not in data2
print([item for item in data2 if item not in data1])
```

Comment: Thanks much Lau for the suggestion & answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 DataFrames, one for each dataset, then outer merge the data frames and select the ones that are not marked as 'both'.

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
df = df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'right_only']
```

After this, you can just print the new data frame.